# Throw warnings rather than errors in testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I'm writing unit tests for a package and there are some tests where I don't want the tests to throw errors if they fail but to instead give warnings.

This isn't my real code, but let's say I want to test something like:

```r
add_x_y <- function(x, y) x + y
expect_equal( add_x_y(2, 2), 3 )
```

The output is an error:

```r
Error: add_x_y(2, 2) not equal to 3.
1/1 mismatches
[1] 4 - 3 == 1
```

Is there a variant or alternative function that would throw a warning rather than an error for this check?

Comment: `if (!isTRUE(all.equal(add_x_y(2,2), 3))) warning("abc")` but presumably you're looking for something idiomatic/`testthat`-ish?

Comment: That's a nice suggestion. And you're right, I'm hoping for something that will work nicely as a drop-in replacement for the usual behavior of `expect_` functions from `testthat`.

Comment: Not sure about a solution specific to `testthat` but you could wrap the test in `tryCatch()` to output a warning in place of an error - `tryCatch(expect_equal(add_x_y(2, 2), 3), error = function(e) warning(e))`.

Comment: @27ϕ9 That would actually work great. I think for my purposes it would work well for me to use your suggestion and make wrappers around `expect_equal()` and friends, such as `expect_equal_or_warn <- function(...) tryCatch(expect_equal(...), function(e) warning(e))`. Would you like to submit this as an answer?

Comment: @bschneidr - thanks - done.  I used your function wrapper as the answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: The `purrr` functions [`safely`/`quietly`/`possibly`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html) may be of use here too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of an approach specific to `testthat` you could use general error handling to output a warning in place of an error.

```
expect_equal_or_warn <- function(...) tryCatch(expect_equal(...),
                                               error = function(e) warning(e))

expect_equal_or_warn(add_x_y(2,2), 3)

Warning message:
add_x_y(2, 2) not equal to 3.
1/1 mismatches
[1] 4 - 3 == 1
```